# Frustrating recursive functions in JS

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I've been wracking my brain on this all day, and I still don't get it. Could someone please explain to me, how on earth does this function work?!?!?!

```js
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if (current == target) {
      return history;
    } else if (current > target) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
        find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
// → (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

How does it not keep going back and forth calling on itself in an infinite loop?

Comment: It's not infinite. If `current == target`, it doesn't recurse, but returns `history`. Likewise, if `current > target`, it returns `null`. Otherwise it makes a recursive call and potentially a second one. Break open the developer tools, set a breakpoint, and step through the code as it executes.

Comment: It's an interesting piece to analyze, actually.

Comment: I love the heading of this question "Frustrating recursive functions in JS"... Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, that test:

```
if (current == target) {
    return history;
}
```

tests if the solution has been found, and then returns that solution

while that test:

```
if (current > target) {
    return null;
}
```

finds out that ***no solution can be found***, and then returns null.

For example, if you try `findSolution(10)`, you will get null.

Else, if we are not in one of those recursion ending conditions, the code will continue to search and to build the solution string.

So, this code will try to build every possible combination of "+5" and "*3" until it produces either the given number, or null if the combination gives a greater number.

Comment: Thank you! Clear and concise answer!

Comment: I tested your code here: https://es6console.com/ It's quite entertaining to see the result for various values...

Comment: Okay I'm sorry if I'm being stupid here but I've got to ask. When the find function is called it checks for the two conditions and then goes on to again calling the find which again checks for two conditions then calls find which again checks for two conditions  how is that not going on forever? Where does it actually do the math? Sorry again I just don't get it...

Comment: Each string subdivises in 2 at each recursion. Either it gets +5 or *3. So sooner or later, it will either get the value of the entry parameter (24 in your example) or it will exceed it, and get null, which then stops the process for that branch. You can see it like a tree structure : each branch is a string, growing when either +5 or *3 is added. At some point, it stops, because the condition for continued growth doesn't exist anymore. That conditions is: the result of the formula must be SMALLER than the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `console.log` in the first line of the recursive function and watch what is going on.

I changed the function to a version without `else` parts, because all `if` statements return.

The functionality stays.

In the function `find`, there are two exit conditions and one hidden:

1. Check for target value, (ok, this is obvious)
2. Check if the current value is greater than the target value, then exit with null or any other [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, because the return value is used in the next hidden check.
3. Check with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), if

   ```
   find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`)
   ```

   returns a truthy value and if not return the result of the other function call

   ```
   find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`)
   ```

   with either a truty or falsy value (without check).

Together it takes one at start and tries to add `5` or multiply by `3` until the wanted value is reached.

```js
function findSolution(target) {

    function find(current, history) {
        console.log(current, history);
    
        if (current == target) {
            return history;
        }
        if (current > target) {
            return null;
        }
        return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) || find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }

    return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24)); //  (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```